# setting "Find(What:=" to a column in a different xls file

Tags: vba, excel, find

I currently have a code that opens up an empty workbook and then a master file with 5000+ rows of info. A pop up then appears and asks for a ID. I type in my 6 digit id and the macro goes through column b and copies the row with that id and pastes it into the empty workbook.

My issues is this: I have to type in 65 ids! I get a new worksheet every week that has the 65 ids in it. Is there a way to set the `Find(what:=` some how to reflect the id numbers in the worksheet I get every week and then loop it:?

Here's the code I have:

```
Sub tester()
' tester Macro

    Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
        "C:\Users\Captain Wypij\Desktop\macrotest\temp.xls"
    Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
        "C:\Users\Captain Wypij\Desktop\macrotest\master.xlsx"

    Application.Run "PERSONAL.xlsb!Tester1"

End Sub

Sub tester1()

Dim res As String
Dim cl As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbooks

' operate on the active sheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet

res = InputBox("Enter ID to Find", "Copy Row")
 If res = "" Then
    Exit Sub
 End If


With sh
    ' Find first occurance
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Columns.Find(What:=res, _
        After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True)


        ' if found, select entire row
        Set cl = cl.EntireRow
        ' copy and insert paste data into next row
        cl.Copy

    Windows("temp.xls").Activate

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A9").Select
    If (Range("A9")) > "0" Then Range("A10").Select
    If (Range("A10")) > "0" Then Range("A11").Select
    If (Range("A11")) > "0" Then Range("A12").Select
    If (Range("A12")) > "0" Then Range("A13").Select
    If (Range("A13")) > "0" Then Range("A14").Select
    If (Range("A14")) > "0" Then Range("A15").Select
    If (Range("A15")) > "0" Then Range("A16").Select
    If (Range("A16")) > "0" Then Range("A17").Select
    If (Range("A17")) > "0" Then Range("A18").Select
    If (Range("A18")) > "0" Then Range("A19").Select
    If (Range("A19")) > "0" Then Range("A20").Select
    If (Range("A20")) > "0" Then Range("A21").Select
    If (Range("A21")) > "0" Then Range("A22").Select
    If (Range("A22")) > "0" Then Range("A23").Select
    If (Range("A23")) > "0" Then Range("A24").Select
    If (Range("A24")) > "0" Then Range("A25").Select
    If (Range("A25")) > "0" Then Range("A26").Select
    If (Range("A26")) > "0" Then Range("A27").Select
    If (Range("A27")) > "0" Then Range("A28").Select
    If (Range("A28")) > "0" Then Range("A29").Select
    If (Range("A29")) > "0" Then Range("A30").Select
    If (Range("A30")) > "0" Then Range("A31").Select
    If (Range("A31")) > "0" Then Range("A32").Select
    If (Range("A32")) > "0" Then Range("A33").Select
    If (Range("A33")) > "0" Then Range("A34").Select
    If (Range("A34")) > "0" Then Range("A35").Select
    If (Range("A35")) > "0" Then Range("A36").Select
    If (Range("A36")) > "0" Then Range("A37").Select
    If (Range("A37")) > "0" Then Range("A38").Select
    If (Range("A38")) > "0" Then Range("A39").Select
    If (Range("A39")) > "0" Then Range("A40").Select
    If (Range("A40")) > "0" Then Range("A41").Select
    If (Range("A41")) > "0" Then Range("A42").Select
    If (Range("A42")) > "0" Then Range("A43").Select
    If (Range("A43")) > "0" Then Range("A44").Select
    If (Range("A44")) > "0" Then Range("A45").Select
    If (Range("A45")) > "0" Then Range("A46").Select
    If (Range("A46")) > "0" Then Range("A47").Select
    If (Range("A47")) > "0" Then Range("A48").Select
    If (Range("A48")) > "0" Then Range("A49").Select
    If (Range("A49")) > "0" Then Range("A50").Select
    If (Range("A50")) > "0" Then Range("A51").Select
    If (Range("A51")) > "0" Then Range("A52").Select
    If (Range("A52")) > "0" Then Range("A53").Select
    If (Range("A53")) > "0" Then Range("A54").Select
    If (Range("A54")) > "0" Then Range("A55").Select
    If (Range("A55")) > "0" Then Range("A56").Select
    If (Range("A56")) > "0" Then Range("A57").Select
    If (Range("A57")) > "0" Then Range("A58").Select
    If (Range("A58")) > "0" Then Range("A59").Select
    If (Range("A59")) > "0" Then Range("A60").Select
    If (Range("A60")) > "0" Then Range("A61").Select
    If (Range("A61")) > "0" Then Range("A62").Select
    If (Range("A62")) > "0" Then Range("A63").Select
    If (Range("A63")) > "0" Then Range("A64").Select
    If (Range("A64")) > "0" Then Range("A65").Select
    If (Range("A65")) > "0" Then Range("A66").Select
    If (Range("A66")) > "0" Then Range("A67").Select
    If (Range("A67")) > "0" Then Range("A68").Select
    If (Range("A68")) > "0" Then Range("A69").Select
    If (Range("A69")) > "0" Then Range("A70").Select
    If (Range("A70")) > "0" Then Range("A71").Select
    If (Range("A71")) > "0" Then Range("A72").Select
    If (Range("A72")) > "0" Then Range("A73").Select
    If (Range("A73")) > "0" Then Range("A74").Select
    If (Range("A74")) > "0" Then Range("A75").Select
    If (Range("A75")) > "0" Then Range("A76").Select
    If (Range("A76")) > "0" Then Range("A77").Select
    If (Range("A77")) > "0" Then Range("A78").Select
    If (Range("A78")) > "0" Then Range("A79").Select
    If (Range("A79")) > "0" Then Range("A80").Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone _
           , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate

    Application.Run "PERSONAL.xlsb!Tester1"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider repeating suchquestion on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ next time.

Answer (score 1):

' I would use VBA code, behind the master data sheet. Then instead of looking for your vbs, you must look for your master excel.

' To add taht code, press [Alt]-[F11] while you have your master data open.

```
Public Sub ExtractAll()
    Dim Ids2find As Range, Column2search As Range, Cell2find As Range, FoundCell As Range
    Dim ExtractBook As Workbook, ExtractCellA As Range
```

' Do not prompt yourself to enter the codes one by one. Istead ask yourself to select the range with the codes from the sheet you get each month

```
    Set Ids2find = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the IDs to extract from the master", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

    If Not Ids2find Is Nothing Then
```

' We will not look for the code in the compleet sheet, just in the column with the keys

```
        Set Column2search = Me.Columns(2)
```

' Create your destination workbook

```
        Set ExtractBook = Workbooks.Add
        Set ExtractCellA = ExtractBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
```

' Why not copy the headers too?

```
        Column2search.Rows(1).Copy
        ExtractCellA.PasteSpecial
```

' And advance one cell in the destination

```
        Set ExtractCellA = ExtractCellA.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
```

' Now work your way through the selected cells

```
        For Each Cell2find In Ids2find
```

' Find what you are looking for

```
            Application.FindFormat.Clear
            Set FoundCell = Column2search.Find(What:=Cell2find.Value, _
                After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=True)
```

' copy it and advance again

```
            FoundCell.EntireRow.Copy
            ExtractCellA.PasteSpecial
            Set ExtractCellA = ExtractCellA.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
        Next Cell2find
```

' You can add code to save your workbook here, but I would save manually

```
    End If
End Sub
```

' You will need a way to start it. You can for instance insert a "Forms Control" button on your master sheet. Probably you must first enable your developer tab. I let you google for that.

Comment: Psst OP doesn't actually seem to be using any VBScript. I've removed the tag.

Comment: I'm not surprised. I was missing something in his post to open Excel in the first place.